# sh: command not found

Tags: linux, fortran90

In my Fortran program I want to call the system to run my code (with alias asv20r3). For it I do:

```
call system ("asv20r3 " //filename)
```

But I obtain the following message:

```
sh: asv20r3: command not found
```

Is it necessary to define something more in order to make the system understand that I want to execute the code via the alias asv20r3?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with your current environment (aliases, variables, etc.) not being inherited but the fortran program. Try including a line like 'call system("alias")' to see whether it's true or not.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to Stack Overflow. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark next to it. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following FORTRAN90 program has all the answer to your question :

```
program Test
  print*, 'Printing environment variables : '
  call system("set")
  print*, 'Printing environment aliases : '
  call system("alias")
end program Test
```

The output of the program speaks for itself : environment variables are inherited; aliases are not.

You can either choose to rely on the content of an environment variable (using `call get_environment_variable(...)`) or hardcode the path and/or command like someone else suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to supply the path to asv20r3 in the system call

Answer (score 0):

your program, asv20r3, needs to be in the $PATH of your system.

if it is in the same directory as where you run your main program, than you must tell your system that by pre-pending a "./" to it, such as "./asv20r3".

Comment: Note that asv20r3 is an alias in the parent shell.